# Can't build android project in IONIC framework

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build my test app for android device with IONIC framework using WEB technology.
I installed **IONIC FRAMEWORK** and configured everything with the help of [Ionic Framework Docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html).

And now I am trying to build android app using command line:

```
ionic build android
```

But this gives me *Error* to install the following targets:

```
ERROR: Please install android target: "android-23"
```

I Have a problem to understand about **android-23**. What's this and how to install it for my *android platform tools*.

I also updated **SDK platform tools** and **SDK build tools**.

Answer (score 0):

API level 23 stands for marshmallow ,have you installed the Android SDK successfully .just check this link,https://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html&ei=7Sw_Jjql&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=141&host=www.google.co.in&ts=1458486558&sig=APY536yicvyJBcnb8fM_Ldmz-Kzx9dINVQ

Comment: Thank You. I got my answer.